# Hide Ionic Cordova www folder

Tags: node.js, cordova, web, ionic-framework, ngcordova

There is any way to 'hide' or 'remove' the www folder from assets? But keep the app working the same way?

I know it exists Cordova-Uglify but i don't want that my source code is available for everyone.
Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

In web development, your "source code", or, better, *client source code*, has to be executed on client's browser, so no way you can avoid making it available to everyone is supposed to use it.

All you can do is *obfuscating* it...
See for example [javascriptobfuscator](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/), or [jscrambler](https://jscrambler.com/en/)...

Comment: is jscrambler safe enough?

Comment: If it is safe enough depends on your needs... However, **nothing** is absolutely *safe*...

Comment: mhm, on native apps, the source code is not available i think, no ?

Comment: Of course... For Java apps only byte-code is available... And even on server-side web apps, source code is not available... But, for client-side apps, it is *always* available (even if it is 'scrambled').